# Jacobson radical and idempotents.

Tags: modules, representation-theory

I was reading a book about representation theory and the author said that the following afirmation are obvious

$$ \operatorname{rad}^2(eA)=e\;\operatorname{rad}^2(A) $$

where "e" is an idempotent and $A$ is a $K$-algebra. I had problems to verify, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\mathrm{rad} \ M = (\mathrm{rad} \ A)M$?

Comment: "It is obvious" is textbook-author for (1) I'm too important to prove this, (2) you're too stupid for me to bother proving this, and/or (3) this seems obvious, but I have no idea how to prove it.  I *really* hate it when authors write that something is "obvious" (even when I agree with them that it is obvious).  :\  That being said, a reference to the book you are working out of would be helpful, or at least a brief reminder of what the notations mean.

Comment: I'm working with "Elements of representation theory of associative algebras" of Ibrahim Assem

Comment: @Jim , I tried to use this fact but i did'nt succed

Comment: @Jim Does that equation really happen for all algebras? i was under the impression it didn't, in full generality.

Comment: @rschwieb Oops, I think you're right.  $(\mathrm{rad} \ A)M \subseteq \mathrm{rad} \ M$ is true in general but you probably need some sort of finiteness condition to ensure equality.  But if Luiz is reading the Assem, Simpson, Skowronski book then his $K$-algebras are probably finite dimensional anyway.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, I could believe it holds for all finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: @LuizLara If you have $M(\mathrm{rad} \ A) = \mathrm{rad} \ M$ (note I switched the side because your reference works with right modules) then $\mathrm{rad}^2 \ eA = eA(\mathrm{rad} \ A)^2 = e(\mathrm{rad} \ A)^2$.

Comment: @Jim Yes, the second equality is easy to check. But i can't see how do we use the fact that $radM=MradA$ to prove that $rad^2(eA)=eA(radA)^2$

Comment: $\mathrm{rad}^2 \ M = \mathrm{rad}[\mathrm{rad} \ M] = [\mathrm{rad} \ M](\mathrm{rad} \ A) = [M(\mathrm{rad} \ A)](\mathrm{rad} \ A) = M(\mathrm{rad} \ A)^2$

Comment: @Jim oh, yes... I had a little confusion about the definition of $rad^2$. Because i was working with $rad(eA)$ and i thought that $rad^2(eA)=rad(eA)[rad(eA)]$. But now, i see that $rad^2M=(radM)(radM)$ makes no sense (p.s. Ibrahim's book does not define $rad^2M$). Thank you.